# How do i choose the account Edge uses to sync

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

How do I choose the account Edge uses to sync settings across browsers? There is an account there, but I don't know how to change it to a different account.

Comment: There is a 3rd-party application that can be used like a replacement for synchronizing favorites between accounts/PCs.   Let us know if you'd be interested in exploring that option.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I choose the account Edge uses to sync settings across
>   browsers?

**You can't;** At least not with the current version of Edge.  The account that is used, is the Microsoft Account, linked to the local profile.

> here is an account there, but I don't know how to change it to a
>   different account.

You would have to convert the linked account to a local profile and then link the (new) local account to a different Microsoft Account.

How you convert a Microsoft Account connected account, to a local account, is well documented.  *Its as simply as going to Settings->Accounts and clicking the `Sign in with a local Account instead` link which results in creating a local profile.*

Comment: I am almost certain I have written an answer that explains the process to convert a connected account to a local profile.  If I find that answer I will cite and quote that answer, if I can't, I will just provide more information.  As currently written the answer address the question in it's current form.